# end_of_week returning different dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, datetime

For the project I am working on, I wish to collect the dates for last week's start and end dates. My  week starts with Sunday and ends on Saturday.

**What I want:**

If today is "Sun, 12 Apr 2015" or "Mon, 13 Apr 2015", my last week's start date should be "Sun, 05 Apr 2015 00:00:00" and end date should be "Sat, 11 Apr 2015 23:59:59". I am getting the start date using `DateTime.now.beginning_of_week(:sunday).last_week(:sunday)` and presently getting end date using `start_date + 6.days`. However I wish to use end_of_week method to get my end date.

**What I tried:**

```
DateTime.now.last_week.end_of_week(:sunday) and DateTime.now.beginning_of_week(:sunday).last_week.end_of_week(:sunday)
```

**Issue am facing:**

If DateTime.now is "Mon, 13 Apr 2015", I get the right start date("Sun, 05 Apr 2015 00:00:00") and end date("Sat, 11 Apr 2015 23:59:59"). However if my DateTime.now is ("Sun, 12 Apr 2015") my start date and end date becomes ("Sun, 29 Mar 2015 00:00:00") to ("Sat, 04 Apr 2015 23:59:59"). My guess is this behavior is because the week in ruby starts from Monday. But in my case, I am starting the week from Sunday and still I am getting incorrect dates.

Is there a way I can achieve what I want using end_of_week, or whatever I am doing now to get the end date is the best way to go.

Comment: Well-stated question! If today is Sunday, how about returning tomorrow's last-week start and end dates?

Comment: This is a good idea, but will likely fail in one case. Although I haven't used Saturday in my examples, if today is Saturday, this would give me current week's dates.

Comment: Note that you can write `start_date + 6`, rather than `+ 6.days`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPD** The answer is changed because of misunderstanding of original question.

```
▶ dt = DateTime.parse "Sun, 12 Apr 2015"
#=> Sun, 12 Apr 2015 00:00:00 +0000
▶ [
▷   (dt - 1.week).beginning_of_week(:sunday), 
▷   (dt - 1.week).end_of_week(:sunday)
▷ ]
#=> [
#  [0] Sun, 05 Apr 2015 00:00:00 +0000,
#  [1] Sat, 11 Apr 2015 23:59:59 +0000
#]
```

Comment: As per the ruby docs, end_of_week(#day) says #day should be start of the week - http://apidock.com/rails/v4.1.8/DateAndTime/Calculations/end_of_week, so I was putting sunday in end_of_week(#day). end_of_week(:saturday) gives me date of friday.

Comment: I am looking for Sun, 12 Apr 2015 00:00:00 to Sat, 18 Apr 2015 23:59:59

Comment: Added the time in my post to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thanks @mudasobwa! I tried the solution and works if my DateTime.now is "Sun, 12 Apr 2015". But if my DateTime.now changes to "Mon, 13 Apr 2015", this returns me start date as "Sun, 12 Apr 2015 00:00:00" and end date as "Sat, 18 Apr 2015 23:59:59"

Comment: Oh, sorry, man, I just played with `last_week` and consider it’s safer to use `dt - 1.week`. Please see an update; that’s not exactly what you have requested, but at least it works.

Comment: No prob @mudasobwa... I appreciate you helping me! Your solution works in both scenarios of Mon and Sun too. I think I can eliminate complete use of last_week method and can do "-1.week". I was trying to figure out if I can make direct use of beginning_of_week and end_of_week methods without doing much calculations.

Comment: Glad that it was helpful.